# How to resume data migration from the point where error happened in ssis?

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, data-migration, checkpoint

I am migrating data from an Oracle database to a SQL server 2008 r2 database using SSIS. My problem is that at a certain point the package fails, say some 40,000 rows out of 100,000 rows. What can I do so that the next time when I run the package after correcting the errors or something, I want it to be restarted from the 40,001st row, i.e, the row where the error had occured.

I have tried using checkpoint in SSIS, but the problem is that they work only between different control flow tasks. I want something that can work on the rows that are being transferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no native magic I'm aware of that is going to "know" that it failed on row 40,000 and when it restarts, it should start streaming row 40,001. You are correct that checkpoints are not the answer and have plenty of their own issues (can't serialize Object types, loops restart, etc).

How you can address the issue is through good design. If your package is created with the expectation that it's going to fail, then you should be able to handle these scenarios.

There are two approaches I'm familiar with. The first approach is to add a [Lookup Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx) in the Data Flow between your source and your destination. The goal of this is to identify what records exist in the target system. If no match is found, then only those rows will be sent on to destination. This is a very common pattern and will allow you to also detect changes between source and destination (if that is a need). The downside is that you will always be transferring the full data set out of the source system and then filtering rows in the data flow. If it failed on row 99,999 out of 1,000,000 you will still need to stream all 1,000,000 rows back to SSIS for it to find the 1 that hasn't been sent.

The other approach is to use a dynamic filter in your WHERE clause of your source. If you can make assumptions like the rows are inserted in order, then you can structure your SSIS package to look like `Execute SQL Task` where you run a query like `SELECT COALESCE(MAX(SomeId), 0) +1 AS startingPoint FROM dbo.MyTable` against the Destination database and then assign that to an SSIS variable (@[User::StartingId]). You then use an expression on your select statement from the Source to be something like `"SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable T WHERE T.SomeId > " + (DT_WSTR, 10) @[User::StartingId]` Now when the data flow begins, it will start where it last loaded data. The challenge on this approach is finding those scenarios where you know data hasn't been inserted out of order.

Let me know if you have questions, need things better explained, pictures, etc. Also, above code is freehanded so there could be syntax errors but the logic should be correct.

Comment: Thank you.... I think the second approach will help me to resolve the issue. thanks for responding.